# disable form field if data is exist in database

Tags: django, forms, django-rest-framework

I want to enter the username and disable username field if already exists during form initialization.

I want the username text field disabled if the username exists in the database.

```
class AppUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=AppUser
        fields=['username','password']


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)        
        user_id = self.request.POST.get('user_id')
        if AppUser.objects.filter(usernbame=user_id).exists():
            self.fields['username'].disabled = True
```

Views.py

```
 #u=AppUser.objects.get(pk=id)
    if AppUser.objects.filter(stu_id=dstu_id).exists():
        u=AppUser.objects.get(stur_id=stu_id)
        username=u.username
        password=u.password
        form = AppUserAuthForm(initial={'username':username, 'password':password})
    else:
        form = AppuserAuthForm()
```

Comment: if it is a register form you can throw error message if username already exists in database

Comment: No, this functionality not required in my case. I just want to render username in the disabled text field if it exist, else editable or user can enter the fresh username in the input field.

Comment: your user is not logged in user, then how you will get user id or username?

Comment: check logic in views.py

Comment: when it will be initialized with username and password, the username should be in a disable state.

Comment: And at blank form initialization, both fields should not be disabled i.e. fields should be editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access `request.POST` data in your form's `__init__` you need to pass the `request` explicitly when creating a form instance. And you need to remove int from the kwargs before calling `super()` because else an error regarding an unexpected keyword will be raised. So in your view something like

```
form = AppUserAuthForm(initial={'username': username}, request=request)
```

and in your form's `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    request = kwargs.pop('request')
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    user_id = request.POST.get('user_id')
    # Your other code
```

However, as you are using a ModelForm why not make use of the ModelForm capabilities rather than doing it all manually?

Your view could be

```
if AppUser.objects.filter(stu_id=dstu_id).exists():
    u=AppUser.objects.get(stur_id=stu_id)
    form = AppUserAuthForm(instance=u)
else:
    form = AppuserAuthForm()
```

and your form's `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.instance.pk:
        self.fields['username'].disabled = True
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The second option worked for me. Great.